# Using PromptforLetter and DisplayLetter in C#

Tags: c#

Below is a homeowrk assignment I've been working on.

I need to create a class called FormattedOutput in a file called FormattedOutput.cs.  That class will have the following methods:
char PromptforLetter(void) - this method will return a value
void DisplayLetter(char letter) - this method will accept a value to display

Main should be in a file named mainModule.cs 
Main will PromptforLetter for each character in your name and store each character into a char data type.

Then DisplayLetter(letter1) should display each letter as:

the actual letter
the decimal value of the key
the hexadecimal value of the key
the octal value of the key
the binary value of the key

Information should be displayed first...
Then prompts for each letter of your name.
Then a Table showing each value
Char          Decimal              Hex            Octal              Binary

Here is the horrible mess I have at this time

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public  class formattedOutput
    {
        char PromptforLetter(string prompt)
        {
            string value;
             char achar;

             Console.WriteLine("A",  prompt);
            Console.WriteLine("L", prompt);
            Console.WriteLine("M", prompt);
            Console.WriteLine("A", prompt);
            Console.Read();
            value = Console.ReadLine();
            achar=Convert.ToChar(value.Substring(0,1));
            return achar;
        }

        void DisplayLetter (char letter)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("A");
            Console.Read();
```

Comment: Probably the problem is in me, but I don't find any meaning in the code which you post ! Please make better structure and try to explain it better. Thank you !

Comment: I reworded my question...the problem is, it's my first c# course, and the code is hard to read because I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Check the answer of Matthew Haugen and ask him if something is not clear and good luck with your education !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly uncertain of what you're going for, and it might help to clear up your introduction to the problem (or instance, we don't need to know filenames and such, just give the relevant details). It also seems like you're asking quite a few questions, so I'm going to focus on what I think you actually mean to ask.

The impression I'm getting is that you are to write a console application in C#, with a method to read a single character from user-input, then another one to echo it back to them using several number formats.

If that is, in fact, the case, you probably want something like this:

```
public char PromptforLetter(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt + " "); // This prints out the prompt with a space, and no
                                 // following line break

    // Now you have a choice. Should you take the first key that is pressed, or 
    // should the user have to press enter?

    // Option 1:
    char ret = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    Console.WriteLine(); // Not necessary, but it improves user experience
    return ret;

    // Option 2:
    return Console.ReadLine()[0]; // take the first indexed character from the
                                  // string entered by the user. Strings have 
                                  // integer-indexers, so you can access single them
                                  // characters in kind of like you would if they were
                                  // a string array.
}
```

Printing the character is a bit simpler:

```
public void DisplayLetter(char val)
{
    Console.Write("Char: {0}", val);
    Console.Write("Decimal: {0}", (int)val);
    Console.Write("Hex: {0:X}", (int)val);
    Console.Write("Octal: {0}", Convert.ToString((int)val, 8));
    Console.Write("Binary: {0}", Convert.ToString((int)val, 2));
}
```

Beyond that, it's mostly just up to you and what the instructor is looking for, specifically.

Comment: Really good explanation. Probably you should write Main method too. You will need to explain about Hex,Octal and Binary probably too. +1, keep with the good work ! :)